# How to get image from web api url?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have a url that when paste it into browser address display an image.This url call a method of webapi that return an image.I need to get image code by string format and save into database  .
I use this code :

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var barcode = client.GetAsync("https://store.zirbana.com/v2/barcode/render?text=234501").Result;
```

This code has result but How can i get image from this?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the content of the response as a byte array and convert that to a base64 string to be saved in the database.

```
public async Task<string> GetBarCode(string attachmentUrl) {
    using (var client = new HttpClient()) {
        using (var response = await client.GetAsync(attachmentUrl)) {
            var bytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
            var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
            return base64String;
        }
    }
}
```

If you meant interpreting the image to then you need to use a barcode reader to scan the image and get the actual code stored in the image.